# Retornando get_FIELD_display de uma lista transformada em dicionário (Django)

Tags: django, dicionário, django-templates

Eu queria transformar a lista a seguir num dicionário:

**lists.py**

```
status_list = (
    ('c', 'cancelado'),
    ('elab', 'em elaboração'),
    ('p', 'pendente'),
    ('co', 'concluido'),
    ('a', 'aprovado')
)
```

Então eu fiz o seguinte:

**Views.py**

```
class ProposalList(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/proposal/proposal_list.html'
    model = Proposal
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProposalList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dct = {}
        for i in status_list:
            dct[i[0]] = i[1]
        context['status'] = dct
        return context
```

E me retorna um dicionário:

```
{'p': 'pendente', 'co': 'concluido', 'elab': 'em elaboração', 'a': 'aprovado', 'c': 'cancelado'}
```

Dai no **template** eu queria fazer:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    {% for item in status %}
        <li name="{{ item }}">{{ get_item_display }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Pergunta**: Porque que não funciona? No caso, get_item_display não retorna nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira como você está fazendo, o `get_item_display` seria um atributo passado anteriormente pelo contexto, quando na realidade ele é um [método](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) criado para cada field que tem um `choices` setado.

Veja que você transformou seu `status_list` em um dicionário, e está percorrendo ele no for, porém este mesmo for só está acessando as chaves do seu dicionário. Seguindo sua abordagem, para conseguir o que quer você deveria fazer algo do tipo:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
{% for key, item in status %}
    <li name="{{ key }}">{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```